# Return JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Currently I'm returning a message from my PHP backend like so:

```
$data = [ 'message' => 'Number doesn\'t exist!'];
$this->set_response(json_encode($data), REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
```

This will create a message looking like this:

```
"{\"message\":\"Number doesn't exist!\"}"
```

I however am hoping to get a message looking like this:

```
{
    "message": "Number doesn't exist!"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$data = [ 'message' => 'Number doesn\'t exist!'];
echo json_encode($data);` expected result return. check your this function `set_response`

Comment: Yes problem in set_response @devpro

Comment: yes agreed, maybe `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` will resolve @HaRsH

Comment: i hope u got the solution now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as second parameter in [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$data = [ 'message' => 'Number doesn\'t exist!'];
$encoded = json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$this->set_response($encoded, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED);
```

***Other Solution:***

```
$data = [ 'message' => 'Number doesn\'t exist!'];
$string = $this->set_response(json_encode($data), REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); // your current result
$decode = json_decode($string,true); // decode the value 
echo json_encode($decode,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); //and use JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES in json_encode()
```

Answer (score 0):

brother you just need to call your json as json_encode($data,true) and decode it like this json_decode($data,true);
Happy Coding
if the above doesn't seem to work 
second try

The \ is to escape the quotes (") that are part of the response.

Use stripslashes() to strip these out.

When a string wrapped in quotes contains quotes, they have to be escaped. The escape character in php is \

Comment: expected result required in json. not in array

Comment: json_encode() has only one parameter. decode has 2 parameter

Answer (score 0):

You must decode the JSON response.

```
json_decode($your_response);
```